# Which home made foods/meals can dog eat?

Tags: dogs, feeding

I don't want to buy packaged dog foods. What meals i can offer for him? E.g spaghetti, bread, milk? I mean not specially prepared food but foods that human eats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't make your own dog food without learning what dogs need in their daily diet first.

**None of your suggestions are healthy dog food.** Especially the salt and spices in human food are unhealthy for dogs. **There are very common ingredients in human food that are harmful or even poisonous for dogs.** You would cause malnutrition and illnesses in your dog if you fed him like that every day.

There are some recipes floating around the internet on how to make dog food at home, but I will not point you to any of them, because:

1. It's very easy to make mistakes, leading to either a deficit of vital components or an excess of unhealthy components.
2. Making healthy meals for a dog is just as expensive as buying dog food, because you need to feed lots of meat.

Comment: *I agree with this - DO NOT feed animals "human" food.* 
I had a family member follow the "raw food" diet with their dog, but it a lot more work and no cheaper than buying dog kibbles/canned foods. It entailed feeding them specific amounts and types of raw meat (do not feed a dog cooked meat, especially with the bone), and supplementing it with the right amount of raw veggies and such for essential nutrients - which must be done with CARE and RESEARCH before proceeding.

Comment: Research has shown that raw food can be healthier if done right. But yeah you need to becareful not to give them too much of certain things, for example heart, liver and rabbit are very rich so should be given in small amounts.

Comment: I never understood this thing. Dogs are opportunistic predators. If there is no better, they can eat even "faeces" in the wild. If their body feels something poisonous, they can very easily vomit, much easier than we. In many families, dogs are allowed to eat from the food of the humans, regularly, and there is no experience that it had been harmful for them. I don't believe this thingy et al.

Comment: @GraySheep The biggest problem is that you, as the owner without medical training, cannot directly see the effects bad food has on a dog. The most common are cardiovascular diseases caused by too much fat and kidney failure due to poisoning, but there are many more like diabetes, joint problems or cataracts. In the wild no one will shed a tear if a dog or wolf dies at age 5, but we try to prolong the lives of our domesticated dogs as much as possible. I'll look for an existing question or ask a new one to give you more details.

Comment: @Elmy It is right. I suspect, many of the question posters here have a strong unsaid wish to decrease theit vet costs. I also suspect, that most of them simply don't neuter their pet. Holding a dog only on dog food requires to use many, high-quality food, and a regular switch of their types. It is very costly.

Comment: @GraySheep I've had a look through our old questions and found that high quality food verifiably prolongs the life of domesticated dogs. Have a look at [Risks of Low Quality Dog Food](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/11182/12501) and [What to look for in dog food](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/9781/12501).